# How to use special character in android *.xml files?

Tags: android, view, character, quote

There is a similar question but that didn't answered everything.
1. In layout.xml how can I use double quote? The following code gives an error

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="This is double" quote."
//The text have only one double quote (after double) 
//This is double" quote.
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

I tried to use &quot; and \" but neither helped. I can get the double quote from strings.xml but I want to keep the text in layout.xml (It doesn't make sense to write a separate string file if I want to show a small piece of text, like degree-minute-second (°'")). How can I do this?

2. In strings.xml I cannot use < or >.

   <string name="x">The <sub> terranean tunnel</string>

The <sub> gets ignored, though I want to show that part (with the less-than and more-than signs). Though I have not tried it but I think that using \<sub\> may help. But in that case if I want to show \<sub\> (with the backslash) how can I do that?

As I said in the first line, I know that this is a duplicate question. But the solution in the other question didn't helped me (&quot; doesn't work for me). Moreover I have asked two questions (2. related with strings.xml).

Comment: `I want to keep the text in layout.xml` why? that's against all recommendations.

Comment: also, a little search wouldn't hurt you. this is an obvious duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Try reading this page: http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html it looks like it contains the answer you are looking for.

In summary, here is the list of escaped characters and the escape code

```
Character   Predeclared Entity
&           &amp;
<           &lt;
>           &gt;
"           &quot;
'           &apos;
```

Referenced from the link.

For your case, try something like this

```
android:text="&quotThis is double&quot quote."
```

Comment: The text have only one double quote.
This is double" quote.

Comment: android:text="This is double&quot quote."